# SQL Server locking on SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have built a web service that queries new data using an iterator (bigint) from a big table (100+ million rows) in an accounting system (SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition).

The provider of the database has forced us to read uncommited transactions to ensure that we do not lock up the table for inserts (updates are never made).

Lately this has caused us trouble due to rollbacks. The accounting system has rollback rows that was already read by the web service due to errors and timeouts causing my system to store data that never should existed.

I think reading commited data would solve this but the accounting system provider will not let us since they are worried that it will lock inserts into the table.

Can the select actually block inserts and how would we best solve it?

Comment: how about using 'with nolock'

Comment: That is basically what I am doing (read uncommited) and that causes the problem. What I want to do is to read commited without causing insert locks.

Comment: Your provider needs to set the database to read committed snapshot isolation: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/. That allows you to read the records as they were prior to a transaction starting without blockig a transaction.

Comment: Yes that would be good, but that cannot be done without a lot of fuzz since it is a product used by a lot of customers.

Comment: It's the solution to both of the problems you describe: reads not blocking writes, and not reading uncommitted transactions

Comment: Thanks, but it just not possible since we do not own the database and can not just enable snapshot isolation in it.

Comment: Maybe you could depend on timing, if you know transaction allways take less than X amount of time only process data older than X amount of time.

Comment: You want a *technical* solution to the fact that your provider is only allowing you to use a mode where it's known that dirty reads are a possibility, and you want to avoid dirty reads? This is a *people* problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting only data that you know isn't dirty (i.e. in the process of being written).  For instance, if your table has a column `createddate` filled with the date the row was inserted on the database, then create a where condition retrieving only rows inserted after 5 minutes have passed.

**Example**

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, createddate
FROM table WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE createddate < dateadd(minute,-5,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a technical issue as much as a design issue.  I would recommend that you create a new table that is a copy of this table with committed transactions after whatever time frame is necessary to determine the committed data.  Otherwise I would recommend finding another vendor for your accounting system.